# Java equivalent of return function in javascript

Tags: java, javascript, reflection, three.js

I am porting three.js to java with a few of my own changes and additions. However I am having trouble deciding how to handle the reflection.

I need to implement a few of the methods that return functions in three.js, such as THREE.Line3.closestPointToPointParameter. What is the best way to implement this idea in java, or would it be a good idea to just rewrite the method to do a more custom behavior? I am open to ideas and techniques.

Comment: Since Java doesn't support closures until Java 8 (that will be launched this year), you should return an object that implements an interface with the function you want/need.

Comment: have a look:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html

Comment: Could use Scala (for JVM + Java iterop) .. I use Scala in every "Java" project I work on. Blame me for not getting paid enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Functions are not 1st-class citizens in Java, you can not return them or assign them to variables. The Java way is to create anonymous inner classes. For example:

```
interface FunctionInterface {
  float bar(int x);
}

FunctionInterface foo() {
  return new FunctionInterface() {

    @Override
    public float bar(int x) {
      return x;
    }

  };
}
```

Note that Java 8 will introduce Closures, which will make all this less verbose.

Comment: ... and usually these inner classes implement a specific Java interface. Much more cumbersome.